# parse_variables multidimentional empty array?

Tags: add-on-development, module

I have a template tag that uses `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables()` to create a single item with an array of `[items]`.

`Array
(
    ...
    [accessRole] => reader
    [items] => Array
        (
        )
    ...
)`

What should the parsed variables look like if it's empty and what should be it's corresponding template tag if I want to do something different when there are no `[items]`?

An empty array doesn't seem to work (as shown above) when do `{if items}` or `{if "{items}" == ""}`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This is not intuitive at all, but you need an array containing an empty array:

```
$variables = array(
  array(
    'accessRole' => 1,
    'items' => array(array()),
  ),
);

return ee()->TMPL->parse_variables(ee()->TMPL->tagdata, $variables);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob!

`{if items} ... {/if}` gives (which is it trying to trim `[0] => Array ( )`):

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 2584`

Comment: You're right. The empty array solves the `{items}{/items}` tag pair parsing, but not the conditional itself. I'll post another answer.

Answer (score 2):

Upon closer inspection, the conditionals parser does not deal with arrays properly. I think the only thing you can do is use a separate variable to use with conditionals.

```
// {if items_count > 0}
'items_count' => count($items),

// OR

// {if has_items}
'has_items' => count($items) > 0,
```

Comment: It might be worth posting a bug report. Seems reasonable that since arrays are handled well by the tag pair parser, it should work with conditionals, too.

Answer (score 0):

I found setting the array to `""` seemed to work. Albeit screwy.

Something like could be done programmatically:

`if (is_array($variables['items'] AND empty($variables['items'])) $variables['items'] = ""`

for instance.

Comment: I thought this was working. Instead I still get the trim() error as in Rob's answer when {items} has data and the worst part is `{if items}` always returns false. :(